# Cannot generate an App archive using Xcode beta 9

Tags: xcode

I'm in the process of preparing my app for submission to the store and trying to generate a build.

The first step to generate a build is to clean and build an archive.

I recently upgraded my Xcode version to 9.0 Beta.

The Archive menu item is greyed out.

I have tried selecting Build for Running, Build for Profiling and Build for Testing but all none of these makes the archive menu item enabled (see image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOwlI.jpg)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the device "Generic iOS Device" and try again.

Comment: Thanks @dasdom i have changed the device type to Generic iOS Device and i'm able to archive now.